# Sign convention for relative displacment

Tags: kinematics, definition, conventions, relative-motion, displacement

If an object A is $X\ \mathrm m$ behind B,than the relative displacemnt of A wrt B would be $-X$. However is object A was moving towards B(at rest) at a rate of $Y\ \mathrm{m/s}$, then $$V_{ab}=+Y-0=+Y$$
$$S_a=0$$$$S_b=+X$$ $$ S_{ab}=0-X=-X$$

But then the the time taken to approach B would be negative.
It seems I have been taking the wrong signs for relative displacement.

Can anybody explain me why I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I will do:
We set $\vec r_B=0 $, which means $\vec r_A=-x \hat i$ now we know that $\vec r_A=\vec r_B + \vec r_{A/B}$(/B means wrt B)
$$\vec r_{A/B}\vert_{\small {t=0}}=-x\hat i$$
Now we know that $\vec v_B=0$ and $\vec v_A=y \hat i$ which gives
$$\vec v_{A/B}=y  \hat i$$
Now at time $t=T$ we see that A reaches B which means
$$\vec r_{A/B} \vert_{\small {t=T}}=0$$
Now using
$\vec r \vert_{\small{t=T}}=\vec r \vert_{\small{t=0}}+\vec v T$
$$0\hat i=-x\hat i+yT\hat i$$
So no we dont get a negative time

Answer (score 0):

When using variables, don't separate the sign and the magnitude into separate symbols. Instead of saying, "Object A is $X$ meters behind object B, so its displacement is $-X$." Say instead, "The displacement of object A from object B is $X$. Since A is behind B, $X<0$." This way, you don't have to worry about whether to add or subtract these quantities and you can consistently use the formulas you know.

Furthermore, the fact that you have two symbols for the same quantity--$X$ and $S_{ab}$--is confusing. Pick one of these symbols. I would suggest $S_{ab}$ to stay consistent with the rest of your math. If you need your answer in terms if $X$, plug that in at the end when you have fewer signs to deal with.